# Ms Sql Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, exception

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <,    <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

I have Id values as varchar like below.

'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9'

I list above ID list however if ı have more than 1 row , i get above exception.

```
DECLARE @List varchar(255)= (SELECT FIRSAT_PERSONELLER_ID FROM FIRSATLAR) 

DECLARE @X XML
SELECT @X  = '<myxml><nodes><n>' + 
REPLACE(@List,',','</n></nodes><nodes><n>') + 
'</n></nodes></myxml>'

SELECT LTRIM(C.value('n[1]','VARCHAR(50)')) AS item1
FROM @X.nodes('/myxml/nodes') Cols (C)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to extract to the XML variable @List. You can use the XML extensions on a set.

For you particular example I think you would need:

```
SELECT  LTRIM(C.value('n[1]','VARCHAR(50)')) AS item1
FROM    (   SELECT  X = CAST('<myxml><nodes><n>' + 
                                REPLACE(FIRSAT_PERSONELLER_ID,',','</n></nodes><nodes><n>') + 
                                '</n></nodes></myxml>' AS XML)
            FROM    FIRSATLAR
        ) t
        CROSS APPLY X.nodes('/myxml/nodes') Cols (C);
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21698f/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Put a MAX in your subquery:

```
DECLARE @List varchar(255)= (SELECT MAX(FIRSAT_PERSONELLER_ID) FROM FIRSATLAR)
```

But this might not be intended.

You may consider a cursor for each value returned from the subquery.

Alternatively you may put a WHERE clause in order to filter the returned values.

If you need a comma separated list:

```
DECLARE @List varchar(255)
SELECT @List = COALESCE(@List +',' ,'') + FIRSAT_PERSONELLER_ID
FROM FIRSATLAR
```

Comment: what do you mean by reach?

Comment: I have list data , it has 10 rows.I only get 1.row

Comment: Do you need a comma separated list out of the subquery?

Comment: yes , i split Id as comma 1.row (1,2,3,4)-2.row(22,12,33)-3.row(7,5,3)

I only see 1. row it has below to below 1 2 3 4